# what is best way for convert maya py (python) to pyd?

Tags: python, maya

what is best and easy way for convert maya py (python) to pyd ? 
I had explored in this field, but unfortunately none of them was effective and after convert to pyd I can't import my code into Maya.

Answer (score 0):

`pyd` files contain native binary python extensions, usially developped using Python C API and some native language.

`cython` might be the simplest tool that might help you creating `pyd` by compiling a subset of Python source code.

What are you trying to achieve ?